Key Vault Secret issue - Firewall is turned on and your client IP address is not authorized to access this key vault
I am new to Azure Key Vault, trying to add Secrets but it keeps the following error.

Firewall is turned on and your client IP address is not authorized to access this key vault.
Can someone enlighten me on how to achieve this goal?
I am using admin account on this subscription.
Networking settings below:



Could you include Networking settings Portal image of your key vault?

See above networking settings for your information. Thank you @Sridevi

To resolve the error, try adding your client IP address under Firewall like this https://i.imgur.com/NmlsHvF.png

The error occurs if you missed adding your client IP address under Firewall exceptions when key vault is configured with allow access from specific networks and IP addresses option like this:

Initially, I too got same error when I tried to add secret without adding my public IP address under Firewall exception:

To resolve the error, make sure to add your public IP address under Firewall exception like this:

In addition to that, check whether signed-in user is assigned with Key Vault Administrator role or not and make sure to assign when key vault is configured to use RBAC access:

When I tried to create secret now after adding public IP address to Firewall exception and RBAC role, it added successfully like this:


Thank you Sridevi, i have added the IP addresses and also tick "Allow trusted Microsoft services to bypass this firewall" and there goes the Secrets been created.
